# How to find 5-year survival probability of newborns from a life table?

Tags: demography

I was trying to learn cohort component method for population projection from [this link](http://www.cpc.unc.edu/measure/resources/training/online-courses-and-resources/non-certificate-courses-and-mini-tutorials/population-analysis-for-planners/lesson-8/lesson-8-the-cohort-component-population-projection-method) of the webpage of Measure Evaluation. To project the population forward using cohort component method, when the age groups are in 5-year intervals, we need 5-year survival probabilities (please see **Table 8.1** of the above link).

Now, I can find out 5-year survival probabilities from the life table of my country. But how can I get something like the first entry of **Column 4** of **Table 8.1** (which is 0.9809) from a life table? As far I understand this quantity is the probability of surviving of newborns during the 5 year projection period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is calculated is as follows: (1L0 + 4L1)/(5*100,000).